# Maximum Remainder

Tags: java, logic

Maximum remainder

You are given a number N. Write a program to find a natural number that is smaller than N such that N gives the highest remainder when divided by that number. 
If there is more than one such number, print the smallest one.

Can anyone help I think I'm missing something like if 2 numbers will have same reaminders my code would overwrite the minDivisor to the upper value

```
static int findRemainder(int num){
    int maxRemainder=0;
    int minDivisor=0
    int answer=0;

    for(int i = 1; i<num; i++){
        if(maxRemainder <= (num % i)) {
            maxRemainder = num % i;
            if(minDivisor < i && maxRemainder == num%i) {

            } else {
                minDivisor = i;
            }
        }
        return minDivisor;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Also "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." - help center.

Comment: Hmm, I would think that `x = num / 2 + 1` is the answer, for any `num > 2`. The remainder will be `x-1` or `x-2`. For any larger `x` value, the remainder would be smaller, and for any smaller `x` value, the remainder cannot be larger than `x-2`.

Comment: Which means there is never more than one such divisor. However, your code won't work because the `return` statement is inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
int largestRemainder = c % ((c/2) + 1);
```